# Extra parameter/config when installning app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store

Is it possible send a parameter when installing an app from appstore?

My idea is to have a link to the itunes store with some extra argument that's passed to the app when it starts for the first time.

For example a user uses a QR-code to get a link, based on the link I would like to add that specific QR-code (bound to a specific location) to the users favorite.

..fredrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, of course this is not possible.